# Cygwin SSH server works with SFTP but not with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, cygwin, putty, windows-server-2012, sftp

I followed this video reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dL-9k4riBps (tutorial and explanation on how to restrict a user to their home directory with sshd_config, chroot directory and windows user groups, updated to include better user restriction instructions locking the user into their home directory in SFTP) to create an SFTP connection using Cygwin.

Everything works fine when I connect using SFTP Client.

I want to create a normal SSH connection for GIT/PuTTY, however it's not working. It's not even showing me any error. The PuTTY terminal just closes after connecting.

Comment: look on sshd logs

Comment: SSHD log (file inside cygwin/var/log) is fully empty inside

Comment: I got one more file 'lastlog' inside cygwin/var/log which is almost 54M and not readable by notepad++